# Bad Text Printing on First Page using Scientific Linux with HP 6300 OfficeJet

Tags: google-chrome, fedora, printing, printer

I have installed in Scientific Linux 7 (fedora variant), cups, 1.6.3-17 and hplip, 3.13.7-6.

I have also installed hplip-gui.

I am printing to a networked HP 6300 All-in-One.

If I print the test page from the HP Device Manager, the test page is fine.

But when I print from a web page, using Chrome, the first page always has the text about 4 times as large as its supposed to be making the printout useless.

Some items print ok, like a spreadsheet.

I have had the same 4 times large text printing problem using Firefox.

I have looked for anyone reporting this problem. I can't seem to find the appropriate Q&A. I know I'm not lucky enough to be the only one with the problem. :)

Comment: Does it happen with all web pages or just certain ones.  Some web pages aren't printer-friendly.  In some cases, you can improve the output by using one of the print helper add-ins (in Firefox, something like Print Friendly or Print Edit).

Comment: Its only the first page that is bad, the rest of the pages print correctly.

Comment: Sometimes what I see in the print preview window is correct. Sometimes it is not. In either case the print comes out 4 times too big.

Comment: Is the problem with any and all web pages or just certain ones.  Do the problem pages always have a problem, or sometimes those print OK?   It might be useful to post the url's for a few of the pages that are a problem so people can look at the source code.